# getString("daterow") returning different format from 10g to 11g

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a large legacy application which calls resultSet.getString(column) and the column it is calling on is the DATE format in Oracle.  This code worked just fine with Oracle 10g client.  It would return the following:

'2008-05-19 10:03:56.0'

However, when I use the Oracle 11g client (the server has not changed) it gives the following:

'2008-05-19 10:03:56'

Now, I know the right way to fix this is by changing the code to NOT use getString for a date function, but it's a ton of code and we are trying to do this without having to do code changes.

Is there any configuration parameter(s) I can use to fix this on the Oracle client side?

I've tried the following and it doesn't even change the format:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'");
```

This one took off the seconds, but when running a query it is still using the one with seconds.  So I don't think the NSL_DATE_FORMAT update will work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: ResultSet getString() differs between environments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396056/java-resultset-getstring-differs-between-environments)

Comment: Similar, but not a duplicate.  His answer doesn't solve my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread below seems to indicate that the date format is hard coded in the jdbc drivers:

[Java: ResultSet getString() differs between environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396056/java-resultset-getstring-differs-between-environments)

If that is true then the only solutions seem to be:

1. Change all the code to use getDate()
2. Change all the queries to use to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F')

Does anyone see any other solution?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that too, I've come to the realization that it will require a code change.  It's simple to change, I just wanted to avoid it since it is a legacy system.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this in your code:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F'
```

If you have a central point at which Connections are created, you could do it there.

(Here's the source I found so far for [Oracle data/time literals](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ). There's probably a clearer one somewhere.)

Comment: If I call stmt.execute("alter session set nls_date_format('YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.S')"); I get an error (missing equals sign).

Comment: ok I fixed it to work by making it use =, but it won't recognize my date format.  Any idea how I have it put the .S at the end?

Comment: Is it `.FF` for fractional seconds or `.SSSS` for milliseconds?

Comment: Is the format you specify taking effect at all? If you use 'DD-MM-YYYY', is that what you get?

Comment: I also tried chaning the format to something else and it didn't pick up the format change, see the edited question.

Comment: Is this all on the same Connection?

Answer (score 0):

In the client environment, set the environment variable NLS_DATE_FORMAT to the format you need and run your program:

`set NLS_DATE_FORMAT=YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F`

EDIT:

Is it feasible to create a database trigger?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER data_logon_trigger
    AFTER LOGON
    ON DATABASE

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   'alter session set nls_date_format = ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F'' ';
END;
```

This is a brute force method - it affects every logon to the database.

Comment: setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT doesn't do anything.  I've tried using environment variables as well as calling alter session.

Comment: Environment variables on the client? Hmmm. That worked for me :-/ I presume this is Windows?

Comment: No, the original OS was AIX 5.3, the new OS is Redhat Linux.